# Authentication sometimes work sometimes not in debug mode

Tags: angular, .net-core

I want in the production any user have to pass the authentication. So I added canActivate.

```
const routes: Routes= {
   {path: 'test', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: MyComponent}
}; 

@Injectable()
 export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router, private auth) {
      if (!this.auth.isLoggedIn) {
    // redirect the user
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }

  return true;
  }
}
```

It works well, however in my debugger process, I found every time I have to login, it pretty waste my time. So I decided to change a little bit in my component, in this case I don't have to login in debug mode.

```
ngOnInit() {
const path = windows.location.hostname;
   if (path.includes('localhost')) {
      this.processing(); // no login therefore
      } else {
      this.processing();
   }
}
```

However I found that even in debug(localhost), sometimes I have to login but sometimes not.
I think that the logic of my if condition and canActivate conflicts. Maybe sometimes one overrides the other one?

For more details, when I run command line `dotnet run` to start application, authentication works. If I launch the application from Visual Studio(Click F5) then no login required.

In my .net core application, I use sap service. Something like

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
  {
    // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
    // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
      spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check location logic inside AuthGuard and just return true if 'localhost' is included in hostname.

> sometimes I have to login but sometimes not.

because, ngOnInit() is not called everytimes when you try to login.